# Error Compiling Shader when running executable

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, shader

My OpenGl code builds and runs without any errors in visual studio 2019 in Debug mode.

When I run the executable from the output directory, I get the following errors in the console but the application runs as if no error occured (all the textures, uniforms, events seem to work as expected):

```
SHADER_ID_COMPILE error has been generated. GLSL compile failed for shader 5, "":
Failed to compile: 35633
```

I also get several uniform and draw-call errors which I assume is the consequence of the shader failing to compile.

I have used absolute paths for my shader paths.

Shader compile code:

```
Shader(const std::string& vertexShaderPath, const std::string& fragmentShaderPath)
        : m_id(glCreateProgram())
    {
        const GLuint vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, getShaderSource(vertexShaderPath));
        const GLuint fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, getShaderSource(fragmentShaderPath));

        glAttachShader(m_id, vs);
        glAttachShader(m_id, fs);

        glLinkProgram(m_id);
        glValidateProgram(m_id);

        glDeleteShader(vs);
        glDeleteShader(fs);
    }
```

CompileShader function:

```
unsigned int CompileShader(GLenum type, const std::string& source)
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
        const GLchar* src = source.c_str();
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }
```

Comment: reference this [link](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation) for shader compilation and use `glGetShaderInfoLog` to get the error

Comment: @gamercodeman I have used `glGetShaderInfoLog` which only tells me it failed to compile. Note this error occurs only when I directly run the executable. The shaders compile fine when I run the program inside Visual Studio

Comment: Try to print the shader source and check if they get loaded correctly from outside visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code to give us more information about the error and also help yourself for future shader compilation errors

```
            GLint result = GL_FALSE ;
            int logLength ;
            glCompileShader ( SHADER_ID ) ;

            // Check vertex shader

            glGetShaderiv ( SHADER_ID  , GL_COMPILE_STATUS , &result );
            glGetShaderiv ( SHADER_ID  , GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH , &logLength );
            GLchar *shaderError = new GLchar [ ( logLength > 1 ) ? logLength : 1 ] ;
            glGetShaderInfoLog ( SHADER_ID   , logLength , NULL , shaderError );
            if ( logLength ) printf ( "Compiling Shader Error : \n%s\n" , shaderError ) ;
```

use this for every shader ( vertex , fragment , [ geometry ] ) .